# Reset Skill Points

Tags: unepic

I just started Unepic and I feel I put some points into skills I don't need, so are there any reset skill possibilities or should I restart my game?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You receive a quest where you have to collect 100 red and 100 blue essence, after which you get a stone with which you can redistribute your skill-points once.

This is in singleplayer however... In Multiplayer I hear is much easier, you just need coins and you have to finish the 4th Unepic map and that's it.

Comment: Thanks, I just stumbled upon the guy who gave me an orb in exchange for  arcane and blue essence instead :D